# Lost tag synonym questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

Searching for flying here https://stackoverflow.com/tags generates flying-saucer with 146 questions and flyingsaucer with 16 questions.

Clicking on either tag leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flying-saucer with 149 questions. Seems there are 13 UFOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597146/flying-saucer-pdf-converter) that have both tags.

This explains the discrepancy.

We do not change the tags whenever they get synonymized - only when a question is edited, so, some questions that had both tags and that were not edited since they became synonyms are still around.